# Remove first element of sequence, compute cumulative sum, iterate

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients

(This is related to my previous question [General formula for iterated cumulative sum](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1166737/91216).)

Consider the sequence $S_0$ consisting of ones:

$$
1,1,1,1,1,1,\ldots
$$

Now *remove the first element* and compute the *cumulative sum* of this sequence. Call the resulting sequence $S_1$:

$$
1,2,3,4,5,6,\ldots
$$

Again, generate $S_2$ by removing first element from $S_1$ and computing the cumulative sum:

$$
2,5,9,14,20,27\ldots
$$

Then $S_3$:

$$
5,14,28,48,75,110\ldots
$$

And so on.

My question: Is there a general formula for $S_k(n)$?

(In the linked question, the problem is [solved](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1166747/91216) for the cummulative sum *without removing first element*, in terms of binomial coefficients.)

If that helps, actually I'm not interested in $S_k(n)$, but rather in the quotient $S_k(n)/S_k(n+1)$.

Comment: Did you OEIS it?

Comment: From looking up various $S_k$, it appears that a general formula is $S_k(n) = \frac{n}{k!}\prod_{i=1}^k (n+k+i)$.

Comment: @mvw Good point. I'm working on that. Thanks!

Comment: @rogerl I think the upper limit of the product index $i$ is $k-1$: $S_k(n) = \frac n {k!} \Pi_{i=1}^{k-1} (n+k+1)$; or $\frac n k \binom{n+2k-1}{k-1}$. With that minor correction it works in all cases I've tested. Make that an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $0\le k\le n$ let $C_{n,0}=1$ for all $n$, $C_{n,k}=C_{n-1,k}+C_{n,k-1}$ for $0<k<n$, and $C_{n,n}=C_{n,n-1}$; the resulting triangular array is often called *Catalan’s triangle*. Here are rows $0$ through $5$:

$$\begin{array}{ccc}
1\\
1&1\\
1&2&2\\
1&3&5&5\\
1&4&9&14&14\\
1&5&14&28&42&42
\end{array}$$

An easy induction proves that your sequences are the columns of this array, i.e., that your $k$-th sequence is $\langle C_{n,k}:n\ge k\rangle$.

Catalan’s triangle is [OEIS A009766](http://oeis.org/A009766), with lots of references and the closed form

$$C_{n,k}=\frac{n+1-k}{n+1}\binom{n+k}k\;.$$

Comment: Ooh! This is great. In fact my sequence arrangement is precisely this triangle (I stripped the columns for easier presentation in the question).